# Distribution of the median of an exponential distribution?

Tags: distributions, simulation, median, exponential-distribution

Say i have $X_{ij} \sim Exp(\theta)$ for $i=1...n,\;\;j=1...k$. Afterwards I derive $k$ medians for $k$ groups of size $n$ (even number). The median is a random variable say $M_j$.  Do we have any idea about what distribution does this random variable have (theoretically) and furthermore how to compute its c.d.f?

If we do not, in order to approach the unknown distribution, do I have a chance by simply simulating the procedure above?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#The_joint_distribution_of_the_order_statistics_of_an_absolutely_continuous_distribution

Comment: The density of the median can be derived from the cdf and density of the sample. It just happens that the Gamma cdf is not available in closed form, even though it can be approximated through implementations of the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: @Xi'an question updated. May I have a mathematical explanation please, with refrences if possible? It would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You can use some R functions from this posts: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441194/how-to-graph-distribution-of-order-statistics/441232#441232, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303425/variance-of-sample-median-of-normal-distribution/306429#306429

Comment: Also, median is an order statistic, so search this site.

Comment: The reference is the Wikipedia page!